# Does A exists such that for all $f$, $||f||_1 \le A \cdot ||f||_2$?

Tags: normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $E = C^0([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$, is the statement $\exists A \in \mathbb{R}^*, \forall f \in E, ||f||_1 \le A \cdot ||f||_2$ true ? With $||f||_1 = \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx$ and $||f||_2 = (\int_0^1 (f(x))^2 dx)^{1/2}$

Comment: Did you mean to ask if "$\exists A \in \mathbb{R}^{*}, \forall f \in E, ||f ||_{1} \leq A || f ||_{2}$"?

Comment: @TomAriel Yes I edited

Comment: Have you tried using the cauchy-schwarz inequality?

Comment: what is $C^0[0,1]$?

Comment: @uniquesolution $C^0([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ are the functions contiguous from [0, 1] to \mathbb{R}, mistake

Comment: @zonn you should add all the information in your post.

Comment: @Theorem No but I don't know how to use it

Comment: @zonn - Cauchy-Scwhartz is what you want. Learn it and learn to use it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(E,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a real vector space with a scalar product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$. For $x$ and $y$ vectors in $E$, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality  states that
\begin{align}
|\langle x,y\rangle | \leqslant \|x\|\|y\|
\end{align}
In $E=\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$, the scalar product is defined by
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(t)g(t)\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
The $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ norms are defined by
\begin{align}
{\|f\|_2} &= \sqrt{\int_0^1 f(t)^2 \mathrm{d}t} & \|f\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f(t)|\mathrm{d}t  
\end{align}
Thus, if $f \in E$, you can apply the CS inequality to $x= |f|$ and $y = 1$, and
\begin{align}
\|f\|_1 = \int_0^1|f| = \int_0^1 |f|\times 1 \underset{CS}{\leqslant} \left\||f|\right\|_2 \times \|1\|_2
\end{align}
You have to check that $|f|$ and $f$ have the same $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm to conclude.